# Provide an SDK for Unity

Tags: unity, android

I downloaded the SDK from over [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads). Namely, I downloaded and unpacked `sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip`.

What should I do next with the files, to which one of them should I provide a path in Unity in order to build an app for `Android`?

[image]

Comment: I just want to point out that "SDK" means "Software Development Kit" and is in no way tied to Android. So, it's better to mention "Android SDK" to make sure your question is more clear, especially if it's part of your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

> ## 4. Configure the Android SDK path in Unity
>
> The first time you create a Project for Android (or if Unity later fails to locate the SDK), Unity asks you to locate the folder in which you installed the Android SDK.
>
> If you installed the SDK using the sdkmanager, you can find the folder in \platforms\.
>
> Example:
>
> `c:\<android tools install location>\platforms\android–27`
>
> If you installed the SDK when you installed Android Studio, you can find the location in the Android Studio SDK Manager. To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

In **Unity 2018.3** I had to set the root folder:

```
C:\<android tools install location>
```

and NOT the platform one

```
C:\<android tools install location>\platforms\android–27
```